# Django Relating Model to User

Tags: python, django, class, model, foreign-key-relationship

I want to relate the Model of the Note in my web app with the user that created it .I guess the relation should be Many-to-One.So that i can then filter data by user.Help my the right code , explain , do you thing this is the right method to use in order to have separate data for each user.I really want your opinion on that.

```
class Note(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(........) <----- should be something like that
```

Comment: sorry for bad English

Answer (score 3):

You can add that as foreign key to user model,

```
#if you are using  user model provided by django contrib 
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Note(models.Model): 
     #user other fields
     owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: i syncdb but no objects was installed . I run the server ,i tried to create new Note and i get this error . Database error . table note_note has no column named owner_id

Comment: Try to reset db for the app, probably the command is `python manage.py reset <your_app_name>` and then syncdb again.

Comment: python manage.py sqlclear note <-' DROP table note_note . python manage.py syncdb <-' 0 objects installed. python manage.py sqlall note <-' . I can see the new field. I run ther server . But same error.

Comment: For some reason when i re open slqlite browser after sqlclear , i can still see the table note_note. So its not actually droping it.

Comment: I used a query to delete table(note_note). And worked. And i get this eoor when creating new note (i am loggedin). Integrity Error : note_note.owner_id may not be NULL

Comment: @KonstantinosKorovesis, you need to set the `owner` field as well while saving the note.

Comment: I understand. I made the field visible when creating the Note. I then have to choose the user. I want this to be done automatically like the creation date . cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True).

Comment: @KonstantinosKorovesis, refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method and the section next to it.

Comment: ok i ll try getting out of this. If you have any ideas tell me . Thanx